# DNN Database Schema Diagram

Tags: database, schema, diagram, dotnetnuke-5, entity-relationship

I need the Database Schema Diagram for DotNetNuke (ERD) if someone have any idea.
I have searched on Internet but have only found this [link](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/BooksandDocumentation/ProjectandTechnicalDocumentation/tabid/478/Default.aspx) which contains lots of documentations about DNN. I only need the ER Diagram for the DNN Database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link [RI website](http://www.r2integrated.com/blog/index.php/data-model-changes-dnn/) Its for the 5.2.2 CE later versions l would have thought have not changed that significantly.  This company does release ERD's from time to time so worth checking back every so often.